# Which is the best open source ERP to implement, modify, adapt, and extend the functionalities of the MRP for a manufacturing company?

Tags: open-source, source-code, erp, freetype

I am looking for an open source ERP that has the MRP module mature enough to take it as a base and adapt it if necessary, be it from configuration to code modifications assigned to the development team. However this more complete, functionalities and stability have is better.

What recommendations do you have?

So far I have found Odoo, ERPNext and Dolibarr among the most popular.

Thanks, Best Regards.